# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen „jemanden verarschen“, „jemanden veräppeln“, „jemanden verspotten“ und „sich lustig machen über jemanden“?

Tags: meaning, difference

Ich weiß, dass sie fast dasselbe sind. Trotzdem möchte ich gern wissen, was sie genau heißen und in welchen Situationen sie verwendet werden können. Ihr könnt auch gerne Beispielsätze liefern.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> jemanden verarschen

... ist schon etwas derbere Sprache als "jemanden veräppeln" (siehe unten).

Außerdem assoziiere ich mit diesem Begriff auch Situationen, in denen jemand betrogen wird - sich der Täter also auf Kosten des Geschädigten bereichert oder sonst einen Vorteil verschafft.

> jemanden veräppeln

... ist meiner Meinung nach nicht ganz so heftig wie "verarschen".

Außerdem verbinde ich mit dieser Formulierung eher, dass man sich mit jemandem einen Spaß erlaubt, um sich über diese Person lustig zu machen und nicht, um diese Person in irgend einer Weise zu schädigen.

In beiden Fällen ("veräppeln" und "verarschen") bin ich aber auf eine bestimmte Reaktion der anderen Person aus. Die andere Person muss also quasi "mitmachen".

> jemanden verspotten

Beim "Verspotten" geht es lediglich darum, sich über eine bestimmte Person lustig zu machen, ohne dass diese überhaupt anwesend sein muss.

Zum Beispiel könnte ich mich nach einem Streich ("veräppeln") über die betroffene Person lustig machen, indem ich überall herumerzähle, wie die entsprechende Person reagiert hat.

Allerdings interprätiere ich das Wort "verspotten" so, dass es durchaus gewünscht ist, dass der Ruf der Person dadurch geschädigt wird oder dass die betroffene Person dadurch, dass sie vom "Verspotten" erfährt, gekränkt ist.

> sich lustig machen über jemanden

... meinem persönlichen Sprachgefühl nach die harmlosere Variante von "verspotten", bei der eine Kränkung oder Rufschädigung der Person nicht erwünscht ist.

Answer (score 1):

"Veräppeln" is commonly used only in Northern Germany and belongs to the colloquial register. "Verarschen" is decidedly vulgar, of course. The others are stylistically neutral.

Answer (score 0):

Verarschen ist jemanden mit seinem Trick in andere Richtung ziehen, die man gar nicht erwartet und auch nicht gedacht hat, bzw. jemandem etwas schaden.

Beispiel: Marc hat gefälschte Adidas-Schuhe und verkauft sie als Original.
Das ist ein Verarschung.
Es schadet dem Käufer. 
Verarschen kann am Ende sehr schlimm, sogar strafbar schaden.

Veräppeln ist, dass man jemanden lächerlich macht, bzw. sich über jemanden lustig macht. Wenn man an harten Stein trifft, kann sich auch was heftiges rechnen. ;)

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Ich habe versucht, ein paar Rechtschreib-Schnitzer auszubügeln. Bitte noch mal gegenlesen und den Satzbau etc. prüfen - so liest es sich wie unbeholfenes Deutsch.